# Shutdown button is missing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed Windows Server 2012 Standard and shutdown button is missing:

[image]

It should look something like this:

[image]

I know how to shutdown windows with comandline, but that is not what I am asking, I am trying to figure out what went wrong, why it is missing, since other installations of same windows server have it.

Comment: Is the display only showing part of the actual screen and the button is not hidden but just "off screen"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Shutdown button is missing

You are missing [KB2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355).

> The short answer is [KB2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355) needs installing.  HOWEVER, you
>   need to make sure you install the following updates in this order:
>
> - Prerequisite: [KB2919442](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919442)
> - Install [KB2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355) that has multiple downloads in it, which can be directly downloaded from the Microsoft Download Center:
>
>   - [Windows 8.1 x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42327)
>   - [Windows 8.1 x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42335)
>   - [Server 2012 R2 x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42334)
> - NOTE: Once downloaded, these updates need installed in the following order
>
>   - clearcompressionflag.exe
>   - KB2919355 (Reboot after installation, if fixed you can skip the rest)
>   - KB2932046
>   - KB2959977
>   - KB2937592
>   - KB2938439
>   - KB2934018
>
> Once [KB2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355) is installed and you reboot, you should now see
>   the Power and Search buttons on the start screen as displayed below:
>
> [image]
>
> **Final Notes**
>
> Once [KB2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355) is installed, run Windows Updates and you’ll
>   probably need to install a few hundred updates again.

Source [Missing Power and Search Button On Start Screen](http://sigkillit.com/2016/10/28/missing-power-and-search-button-on-start-screen/)

---

#### Workaround

- Move mouse to bottom right of screen adjacent to clock, and then move the mouse up and click on Cog wheel:

  [image]
- This will open the following menu to select different options:

  [image]
- Click the Power button:

  [image]

Source [Where is Shutdown button in Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/37660a40-ff10-4652-afd2-db85da8dd723/where-is-shutdown-button-in-windows-server-2012-release-candidate-?forum=winserver8gen)

Comment: thanks. But my server is not RC. I can shut it down, like you have explained. But I am wonder, why the button is missing, since it is should be present.

Comment: @malakrsnaslava See updated answer :)